# C# DataGrid column Resize in VS 3.5

Tags: c#

Please tell me  how to resize the datagrid column in visual studio 3.5. As I am using Visual Studio 3.5 I am not able to find any property to resize as like in Visual Studio 2012 (AutoSizeColumnsMode)

Comment: you can simply use code like dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 200;

Comment: "Visual Studio 3.5"? Please provide more info, do you want to do it at design time or runtime? Do you AutoSize or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: Hi Mustaan, this works in .NET 4.0 but in 3.5 this property is itself is not there, so please help me out little more. Thanks in advance. In 3.5 it is dataGrid in 4.0 and above it is dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

After i got this code it is working fine...........

```
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Clear();
        DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
        tableStyle.MappingName = table1.TableName;
        foreach (DataColumn item in table1.Columns)
        {
            DataGridTextBoxColumn tbcName = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            tbcName.Width = 80;                
            tbcName.MappingName = item.ColumnName;
            tbcName.HeaderText = item.ColumnName;
            tableStyle.GridColumnStyles.Add(tbcName);
        }
        dataGrid1.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);
```